# How to update a Contentful entry using content-management node module

Tags: contentful, contentful-management

I am trying to update an existing entry in Contentful using the content-management node module.
Here is the code I am using, however I am not able to update the entry nor do I see any error.

```js
var client = contentful.createClient({
    // A valid access token for your user (see above on how to create a valid access token) 
    accessToken: 'accessToken value',

    // Enable or disable SSL. Enabled by default. 
    secure: true
});

var log = console.log.bind(console);

client.getSpace('spaceId value').then(function(space) {
    //return space.getEntries();
    space.updateEntry('Sites', {
        sys: { id: 'entryId value', version: 15 },
        fields: {
            siteName: { 'en-US': 'value' }
        }
    });
}).then(log, log);


res.send('hello');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you update an entry you don't need to pass the content type id as the first argument. You should just pass the data object as the first argument (this will change on the next major version of contentful-management).